# Scala: How to copy string to clipboard through Swing?

Tags: swing, scala

Is there a way to copy a string to the clipboard through Scala?

Similar to Python's:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('this is my text')
r.destroy()
```

This question walks through how to copy a string to the clipboard in Swing, but I need something that will work with Scala as well:  [Copying to Clipboard in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java)

Comment: Check out the answer to the similar java question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591945/copying-to-clipboard-in-java

Comment: @Alexlv I've tried, but I'm not very familiar with how to use java packages in Scala. Just the first line itself would make scala throw a fit:  StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("test"). And yes, I also imported java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection

Answer (score 5):

The linked answer translates directly

```
val clipboard = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard
val sel = new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection("test")
clipboard.setContents(sel, sel)
```

Comment: @spydon yes it does. I just tested it (Debian)

Comment: Sorry, badly worded comment, I meant that it doesn't work reliably on *nix. It doesn't work for me on Arch for example. Seems to be another SO thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242719/copying-to-global-clipboard-does-not-work-with-java-in-ubuntu